# Linq query does not work with .Net Core when using joins

Tags: c#

I have the following linq query that works perfectly in an ASP.Net MVC application:

```
var students = (from stu in db.Students
                        join tmphouse in db.Houses on stu.RoomID equals tmphouse.Location_ID into gr
                        from house in gr.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join tmpsite in db.StudentSites on stu.Student_ID equals tmpsite.StudentId into gs
                        from site in gs.DefaultIfEmpty().Where(x => x.IsCurrent == true && x.PrincipleSite == true && x.StudentId == stu.Student_ID && x.SiteId == siteId)
                        join tmpval in db.StandardValues on site.StartingYearGroupId equals tmpval.SvId into gs1
                        from year in gs1.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        join tmpval2 in db.StandardValues on site.GroupId equals tmpval2.SvId into gs2
                        from grp in gs2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where stu.Current_Record == true
                        && site.IsCurrent == true && site.StatusId == statusId && site.PrincipleSite == true && site.SiteId == siteId
                        select stu);
```

But the same query in a newer ASP.Net Core project returns an error of: by 'NavigationExpandingExpressionVisitor' failed.

I would like to avoid having to write the SQL myself, is this not going to be possible o is there something obvious I have missed?

**SOLUTION**

To those interested in how I had to rewrite:

```
var students = (from stu in db.Students
                join x in db.StudentSites on stu.Student_ID equals x.StudentId
                join tmploc in db.Houses on stu.RoomID equals tmploc.Location_ID into gj
                from loc in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                where stu.Current_Record == true
                && x.IsCurrent == true && x.StatusId == statusId && x.PrincipleSite == true && x.SiteId == siteId && x.StudentId == stu.Student_ID && x.StatusId == statusId
                select new ApiStudent
                {
                    ID = stu.Student_ID,
                    FirstName = stu.First_Name,
                    Surname = stu.Surname,
                    DateOfBirth = stu.Date_Of_Birth,
                    House = loc != null ? loc.LocationName : "",
                    YearID = x.StartingYearGroupId.HasValue && x.StartingYearGroupId.Value > 0 ? x.StartingYearGroupId.Value : 0,
                    Year = x.StartingYearGroupId.HasValue && x.StartingYearGroupId.Value > 0 ? db.StandardValues.Single(n => n.SvId == x.StartingYearGroupId.Value).StdValue : "",
                    GroupID = x.GroupId.HasValue && x.GroupId.Value > 0 ? x.GroupId.Value : 0,
                    Group = x.GroupId.HasValue && x.GroupId.Value > 0 ? db.StandardValues.Single(n => n.SvId == x.GroupId.Value).StdValue : "",
                });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to one of the [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes)  in **EF Core 3.0** and that is: [LINQ queries are no longer evaluated on the client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client)

So write the query in such way that EF Core can convert the expression into T-SQL or  fetch the data into memory and then make your query.

Comment: Thank you, I've rewritten the LINQ and edited question for anyone to see how I corrected